# My attempt at creating a simple histogram results in an TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a basic histogram for the column 'gender'

```
df.gender.describe()
```

```
count     3257765
unique          2
top          Male
freq      2399809
Name: gender, dtype: object
```

This is what I tried, which had worked for my other columns:

```
plt.hist(gender);
```

resulting in:

```
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float
```

and an empty chart.

What am I doing wrong? There are empty spaces in some of the rows, I have tried filling them with '0' and then NaN, converted it to int, but received the same error message.

Comment: plt.hist(gender) seems to not be referring to the dataframe, did you mean plt.hist(df.gender)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this : -
`gender = df.gender.astype(str)`

and after that try to plot this